# Accessing a broken Android phone using a pc

Tags: data-recovery, android, hard-drive-recovery, screencasts

I have an Xperia Z2 phone (Lolipop 5.1)

It was unfortunately ran over by a car.

The display and touch screen were destroyed but the device is still working (to my suprise).

How can I access the phone's apps using my PC ? There are game profiles I need to back up to use on my another phone.

The phone is not rooted.

Comment: Did you have a backup on cloud ? How about replace with a new display ? If your device have some settings enabled, you could try to use android-tools-adb to connect to the device from a linux host. How did you connect the device to the pc, until now ?

Comment: I dont usually connect my device to my PC, usually it's just a usb cable and then I use windows explorer to browse the phone's contents

Comment: Do you have enabled the USB debugging mode in developer mode? If yes then it'll be easy.